# Python Pass by assignment but value is not retained

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, pass-by-reference, pass-by-reference-value

I am having this issue in a large code base so I created a small reproducer below:

Here, I have the following two functions, func2() and func3()

```
def func2(a,b):
     a = 'new-value'
     b = b+1
     return a, b

def func4():
     x,y = 'old-value',3
     func2(x,y)
     print(x,y)
```

The output I am getting is:

```
>>> func4()
old-value 3
```

I thought Python is pass-by assignment and so the `func4()` should overwrite `x` and `y` values by `new-value` and `4`

What am I misunderstanding? Also, how can I change the above code to make `x`, `y` have `new-value` and `4`

Any help is greatly appreciated!.

Comment: That's not how Python assignment works. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: You should understand what is pass-by-value and what is pass-by-reference